# bi-directional communication using socketpair: hangs reading output from child process

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, ipc

I'm trying to use a socketpair to have a parent process provide input to a child process that execs a different program (e.g., grep) and then read the resulting output. The program hangs in the while loop that reads the output from the program that the child execs.. The child dupes stdin and stdout on to its end of the socketpair and the parent and the child both close their unused end of the pair.

Interestingly, if the child execs a program that I wrote (OK, I ripped it off from Stevens Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment) everything works as expected. However, if the child execs grep (or some other standard program) the parent invariably hangs in trying to read the output. I can't tell if the input is not reaching grep or if the grep cannot determine the end of the input or if the output is somehow being lost.

Here's the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void 
sigpipe_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void * context) {
  cout << "caught SIGPIPE\n";
  pid_t pid;

  if (errno == EPIPE) {
    throw "SIGPIPE caught";
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  struct sigaction sa;
  memset(&sa, '\0', sizeof(struct sigaction));
  sa.sa_sigaction = sigpipe_handler;
  sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART;
  sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, NULL);

  int sp[2];
  socketpair(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, AF_UNIX, sp);

  pid_t childPid = fork();

  if (childPid == 0) {
    close(sp[0]);
    if (dup2(sp[1], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO) throw "dup2 error to stdin";
    if (dup2(sp[1], STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO) throw "dup2 error to stdout";

    execl("/bin/grep", "grep", "-n", "namespace", (char*)NULL);
  } else {
    close(sp[1]);
    char line[80];
    int n;
    try {
      while (fgets(line, 80, stdin) != NULL) {
 n = strlen(line);
 if (write(sp[0], line, n) != n) {
   throw "write error to pipe";
 }

 if ((n=read(sp[0], line, 80)) < 0) {  // hangs here
   throw "read error from pipe";
 }
 if (n ==0) {
   throw "child closed pipe";
   break;
 }
 line[n] = 0;
 if (fputs(line, stdout) == EOF) {
   throw "puts error";
 }
 if (ferror(stdin)) {
   throw "fgets error on stdin";
 }
 exit(0);
      }
    } catch (const char* e) {
      cout << e << endl;
    }

    int status;
    waitpid(childPid, &status, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code hangs as grep's output may be less than 80 bytes and you are issuing a blocking read on sp[0]. The proper way of doing this is by marking both sockets as non-blocking and selecting() over both of them.

You also forgot to close(sp[0]) before you wait(), which will leave your child process waiting for input.

Comment: Interesting. By using strace I found that grep is waiting for input after receiving all of the input my parent process had to give (a child process that used sscanf worked fine). I tried using shutdown (for read) on sp[0] but it did not seem to work. I will now try using close instead.

I think I assumed that the sockets were non-blocking by default - I will definitely try explicitly setting the sockets to non-blocking and using select.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot achieve deadlock-free bidirectional communication with a subprocess using UNIX pipes or socketpairs, because you don't have control over buffering in the subprocess.

It just so happens that `cat` can be trusted to read one line and immediately print it, regardless of whether its standard output is a tty, a pipe or a socket. This is not the case with `grep` (and actually most programs using stdio), which will buffer output in-process (in the stdio buffers) and defer the `write()` call until either the buffer is full or the stdio stream is closed (typically because `grep` is about to exit after having seen EOF on input).

You can trick line-oriented programs (including `grep`) into not buffering by using a pseudo-tty instead; take a look at [`libexpect(3)`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/libexpect.3.html). But in the general case, you would have to re-run a different subprocess for each message, which allows to use EOF to signal the end of each message and cause whatever buffers in the command (or pipeline of commands) to be flushed.

See more info about this problem in the [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Another-Process) man page (it's for bi-directional pipes in Perl but the buffering considerations apply regardless of the language used for the main program).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with cat, so the problem is with grep. May be grep output behave differently when connected to something else than a terminal. Or it is not detecting the pattern for some reason.